# What web-based expert resources for Nikon are similar to The Digital Picture for Canon?

Tags: lens, nikon, web, reviews

I've followed Canon photo products for years and I can't go past [this great expert resource](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/) on Canon cameras, lenses and few other accessories photographer should know about and read before buying anything new.

I used Canon non-digital SLR for years, and never really bothered to buy myself a digital version. But I decided to do so this spring.

The thing is that I can buy second hand Nikon DSLR. I know the owner so I know that camera is tip top and not much used. But I'm hesitant on Nikon lenses. Which ones provide good value for the money etc.

**That's why I'm looking for similar web expert resources but focused on Nikon products.**

Comment: Also keep in mind that _some_ of those questions will be completely on topic _here_.

Comment: This question and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14546/who-covers-canon-products-in-a-similar-vein-to-thom-hogans-nikon-coverage need to get together and have a little party.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [Thom Hogan's site](http://www.bythom.com/). He is a professional photographer who uses Nikon gear and writes a lot about them and I do mean *a lot*. Unlike [another Nikon photographer](http://www.kenrockwell.com/), his opinions are usually very well balanced.

Comment: He's a little less balanced when speculating _outside_ of Nikon, though.

Answer (score 2):

[NikonGear.com](http://nikongear.com/) has reviews and an active forum

Also [NikonCafe](http://www.nikoncafe.com/vforums/) has very active forums and you can find reviews and comments on just about anything Nikon-related.

You have to take some of his advice with a grain of salt, but [Ken Rockwell](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/) has a ton of information on Nikon equipment, sample shots, comparisons, history of various lenses, good explanation of all the Nikon terminology (AF-D, AF-S, AI-S, VR, IF, ED etc etc)

Comment: A *very large* grain of salt.  Some of the stuff he just flat out makes up (and will say so!).  I'd vote this up if it didn't have KR in it.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these is *just* Nikon (although DTown TV used to be), but [dpreview.com](http://www.dpreview.com) has a lot of good Nikon reviews and an active forum, and [DTown TV](http://kelbytv.com/dtowntv/) is a nice place to pick up tips on gear and technique in a podcasts format.