# Who covers Canon products in a similar vein to Thom Hogan's Nikon coverage?

Tags: canon, web, reviews, thom-hogan

I'm looking to learn a bit about Canon's history, products and reviews and wondered if there were any reviewers that do work focused on Canon's (D)SLR products. The publications and [web site of Thom Hogan](http://bythom.com/) are very nice for learning about the history, usage and informed speculation about future product directions. Can anyone suggest some authors in print or web that might be worth a look?

Comment: This question and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9530/nikon-web-expert-resources need to get together and exchange phone numbers, have lunch, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Bryan Carnathan's [The Digital Picture](http://thedigitalpicture.com/) comes closest

Comment: I saw that site linked here when I was researching if this question was already asked - but was put off by all the flashing ad content. I'll save a few using instapaper to read offline and give him a shot. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Adblock plus + Firefox FTW

Comment: I forget about the tools to get rid of ads. Thanks for that reminder and the good answer. I'll pop a few of Bryan's articles into [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com) or [Readability](http://www.readability.com) and see them for the content. :-)

Comment: It'd be nice if your answer could describe/compare the two authors....